# Is there a rank for higher degree homogeneous forms analogous to that of quadratic forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, multilinear-algebra

Given a quadratic form $Q(x_1, ..., x_n)$, there is a natural notion of rank defined by looking at the rank of the unique symmetric matrix associated to the quadratic form, i.e. we consider the symmetric matrix $A$ such that
$\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = Q(\mathbf{x})$.

Suppose we have a $F(\mathbf{x})$, a degree $d$ homogeneous form. I naively thought that perhaps the rank of $F$ should be defined to be the rank of a hypermatrix $A$ attached to $F(\mathbf{x})$ (Assuming such notions makes sense). But I have never seen anything like that in the literature. 
So perhaps there are issues if one wants to define a rank of forms this way.

I was wondering if someone could explain me why considering this may not make sense or not considered? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

When $F$ is a degree $d$ homogeneous form on $n$ variables in a finite field ${\bf F}_q$, in the regime when $n$ is large and the order of the field and the degree is small, there are two related notions of rank that are useful.  One is an "algebraic" notion of rank - $F$ has rank at most $r$ if $F(x)$ can be expressed as $F(x) = f( Q_1(x),\dots,Q_r(x))$ for some forms $Q_1,\dots,Q_r$ of degree strictly less than $d$, and some function $f$.  (For comparison, note that a rank $r$ quadratic form $F(x)$ can be written in terms of $r$ linear functions of $x$.)  See for instance [this paper of Ben Green and myself](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.3191.pdf) where this notion is used to control the equidistribution of $F$.

A related notion is the "analytic" notion of rank introduced [by Gowers and Wolf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.2208v1.pdf) - a form $F$ has analytic rank $r$ if the exponential sum $\frac{1}{q^n} \sum_{x \in {\bf F}_q^n} \chi( F(x) )$ has magnitude $q^{-r/2}$, where $\chi$ is some fixed character on ${\bf F}_q$.  For quadratic forms in odd characteristic this matches the usual notion of rank by the familiar properties of Gauss sums.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Does the algebraic rank you mentioned ever been used for forms over $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$ before? Also if we define algebraic rank analogously for forms over these fields, would you also expect it could control equidistribution? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any such use in the literature.  It's also not clear what equidistribution would even mean when the range of the polynomial is non-compact - one may need to do some sort of "resolution of singularities" of the polynomial at infinity before one has a meaningful question to ask here,

Answer (score 6):

The most basic notion of rank for a homogeneous symmetric $d$-form $F$ is the dimension $k$ of the span of the partials
$$
F_i = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}
$$
in the space of polynomials of degree $d{-}1$. One always has $k\le n$, and it is always possible to write $F$ as a polynomial in $k$ variables (and no fewer).  This is an elementary result.

There are other notions, such as the *monomial rank*, i.e., the least number of monomial terms needed to express $F$ with respect to some basis of the variables, which need bear no relation with $n$ (other than being bounded above by a constant depending only on $d$ and $n$).  There is also the *power rank*, which is the least number of terms needed to express $F$ as linear combination of pure $d$-th powers. As far as I know, neither of these is easily computable when $d>2$ and $n$ is not small.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering if you could clarify something: we have a symmetric form $F$ in $n$ variables, and then you say it can be written as a polynomial in $k$ variables. I am confused with what you meant by this. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyT.:  What I meant was, for example, this:  The quadratic form $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ uses two variables, but it is clearly $z^2$ where $z = x+y$, so by a change of variables, it can be written as a quadratic form in one variable, namely, $z$.

Answer (score 5):

Such notions are defined for tensors.
A [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) can be seen as you said like, a hyper matrix $A\in\Bbb R^{n_1\times \ldots \times n_d}$ with $n_1,\ldots,n_d\in\Bbb N$. Where $A$ has $d$ indices instead of $2$, i.e. $A_{j_1,\ldots,j_d}\in\Bbb R$ for $j_i=1,\ldots,n_i$ and $i=1,\ldots,d$.
There are several notions of rank defined for tensors. You have the [multilinear rank](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479896305696) (based on one generalization of the singular value decomposition), the rank given by the [canonical polyadique decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition#Definition) (another generalization of the SVD), the [border rank](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0487v3.pdf) and the [cactus rank](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2197v2.pdf) (more abstract concepts). There are other types of decompositions ($\approx$ generalizations of the usual spectral decompositions) which somehow induce other possible notions of rank.